# XCODE, building for iOS - undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, armv7

looks like I am not the first, who is asking about this issue but I need to try. Does anybody encountered this problem?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcher", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in gpg(GPGClearcutLogger.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcherService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in gpg(GIPNetworkImage.o)
  "_GTMMethodCheckMethodChecker", referenced from:
      +[NSDictionary(GTMNSDictionaryURLArgumentsAdditions) xxGTMMethodCheckMethodNSString32] in libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMNSDictionary+URLArguments.o)
      +[NSDictionary(GTMNSDictionaryURLArgumentsAdditions) xxGTMMethodCheckMethodNSString33] in libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMNSDictionary+URLArguments.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It looks like, some Google Play dependency is causing it, if I got it right. I tried to switch some values in XCODE recommended in other threads with similar issue. Namely build settings -> architectures, valid architectures, supported platforms, base sdk, active architecture only. Also no changes, still the same error during linking. cocoapods are installed

I use XCODe 8.1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods to include GooglePlayGames or did you import it manually?

Comment: actually the project is assembled by Unity, so I am not 100% sure, but I believe, it is using cocoapods since, it informs me about it after constructing the xcode project.

Comment: I don't know Unity at all but do use CocoaPods. GTMSessionFetcher/Core is a dependance of GoogleSignIn witch is a dependance of the pod GooglePlayGames. If you have a podfile, close Xcode, running `pod install` then `pod update` and open the workspace file (not the project) and build. Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you, but it unfortunatelly didn't help. it looks like Unity already did those operations when scaffolding xcode project. so manually calling pod install and pod update made no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by myself. The key is to edit the pod file like this (tested with the unity 5.3.6f1, GPG games plugin 0.9.34 and xcode 8.1):

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Unity-iPhone' do
pod 'GooglePlayGames', '5.1'
end
```

then you need to run `pod install` and it works!